# How to remove marker grouping in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

[image]

I have markers without grouping. How to remove this marker grouping?

Comment: Are you the developer for the map, or just a visitor?

Comment: I'm web developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your markers are added to a clustering group, probably an [`L.markerClusterGroup`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster).

Just use a simple [`L.layerGroup`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#layergroup) instead.